# Help me with analysis question on sequences.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Question: Let $(c_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ be a sequence such that $c_n =\frac{1}{n^2}$ if $n$ is odd, and $c_n = \frac{1} {n^4}$ if $n$ is even. Prove
that $c_{n+1} > c_{n}$ for infinitely many values of $n$. Also, show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} c_n $ converges.

Attempt: Now I want to do induction for the first part but that proof is throwing me off. With the base of $n = 1$, I get $\frac{1}{16} > 1$ which is not true. I don't know if I am thinking this right or if there is a typo. For the second part, if the first part is true, then we cannot use alternating series test. I was leaning towards the ration test, but I am leading to a problem. Do I have to test the casea when n is even and odd? Please give me hints on how to solve this! Thank you very much guys!!

Comment: You're asked to show $c_{n+1} > c_n$ for *infinitely many* $n$, not for *all* $n$.  Induction in its usual form isn't really suited for proving this kind of statement.  Have you tried making a table of values for $(c_n)$ to see if you can find some $n$ for which the statement is true?

Comment: Hint: $(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1<(2n)^4=16n^4$ for all $n\geq1$.

Comment: For the second part, note that $\sum c_n$ converges, and that absolute convergence implies convergence.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes I have. It works for n = 2, n = 4 and all the other even n values. But when n is odd the statement is not true. Do I have to prove this for the even terms then?

Comment: What do you think?  You're asked to show a statement is true for *infinitely many* $n$.  You have convinced yourself through numerical evidence that the statement is true for *all even* $n$.  Do the even numbers count as an infinite set?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes, even numbers are a countably infinite set so I would prove this in the context of the even numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If $n $ is even then

$$c_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$
and
$$c_n=\frac {1}{n^4} $$ but

$$n^4-(n+1)^2=$$
$$(n^2+n+1)(n^2-n-1)= $$
$$(n^2+n+1)((n-1)^2+n-2)>0$$ for $n\ge2$.

for the series, we have

$$|(-1)^nc_n|\le \frac {1}{n^2} $$ and comparison test.